Geolocation Issue in Flutter WebView
I created a website to find the exact location using the Geolocation API, and it works properly on my website. However, I converted it into a mobile app using Flutter WebView, and now I encounter an issue.
Here's the Flutter WebView code I'm using:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://weblink",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

pubspec.yaml code
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.9"

When I try to use this app on my mobile, I get the error message: "Error getting geolocation: User denied Geolocation". Additionally, the app does not prompt for location access permission.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the app requests location permissions correctly?
I am expecting detailed clarification to solve this issue.
